# Redireccionar a pantalla Blade desde JavaScript con Fetch en Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel-8, fetch, blade

Estoy tratando de hacer una redirección desde una plantilla "Blade" a otra distinta, pasando datos en la redirección.

Tras realizar unas validaciones de datos insertados tengo este botón en la plantilla origen:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <button id="next" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled">
        Siguiente
    </button>
</div>
```

En el archivo ".js" hago la verificación para habilitar el botón y enviar la petición "GET" al controlador:

```
document.getElementById("select3").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    document.getElementById("next").disabled = false;
})

document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    fetch("prelogin/" + document.getElementById("select3").value, {
        method : "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken
        }
    }).catch(error => console.error(error));
})
```

La ruta de la petición "GET" es:

```
Route::get('/prelogin/{id}', [PreloginController::class, 'prelogin']);
```

Y el controlador es el siguiente:

```
public function prelogin(Request $request) {
    if (isset($request -> school)) {
        $object = User::findOrFail($request -> user -> id);

        return view('login', compact("object"));
    } else {
        return response() -> json(["message" => "Invalid user"], 400);
    }
}
```

El problema es que no se carga la plantilla de Blade, aunque en la respuesta de la petición, en la sección "Red" de "Chrome" si que me aparece como parte del mensaje en vista previa:

[image: Vista previa en "Red" del "DevTools" de "Chrome"]

¿Alguien podría decirme que estoy haciendo mal?

Un saludo.

Comment: Buen día, en el blade que usas para la vista después de oprimir el botón ¿Estás utilizando `@extends('layouts.app')` donde `layouts.app` es el nombre y ruta de tu plantilla?

Comment: Buenas, estoy usando un **layouts master** y tengo esto: **@extends('layouts.master')**, además de que englobo el código tengo **@section('content')** para inyectarlo en el **layouts master**.

Comment: Si escribes esa ruta en el navegador y la abres sin utilizar el botón para redireccionar, ¿La vista carga correctamente?

Comment: Si se carga, aunque sin los estilos estilo que están en la plantilla del **header.blade.php**.

Comment: Ok, pero la plantilla "layouts master" se muestra correctamente? Es decir si vas a la ruta de forma directa el layout si se ve y si vas a la ruta a través del botón el layout no se ve?

Comment: Exacto. al usar la **URL** se muestran los la plantilla **layout master**, pero como te digo, se ve sin estilos. Pero si intento ir a través del botón no se llega a cargar la pantalla, se queda en la pantalla que tiene el botón.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente la solución más óptima que puede encontrar es la siguiente:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <button id="next" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled" onclick="login()">
        Siguiente
    </button>
</div>

function login() {
    window.location.href = "/prelogin/" + $("#select3 option:selected").val();
}
```

En primer lugar modularice la redirección, añadiendo el control del "onclick" al botón, y sin hacer la petición con "fetch" hago una redirección por "URL" usando "window.location.href".

Answer (score 1):

aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo lo debes implementar:

En el archivo route:

```
Route::get('/show-all-prescription', 'prescriptionController@show_all_prescription')->name('show-all-prescription');
```

Luego en el archivo blade

```
window.location.href = "{{ route('show-all-prescription')}}";
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos :)

Comment: Buenas, gracias por tu respuesta, pero si te fijas bien, la redirección la estoy haciendo desde un archivo **js** y no desde **Blade**, por lo que no me sirve del todo.